# Very simple Firestore transaction fails

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm struggling with a super simple transaction. It always fails with the message "Transaction failed all retries" but there are no error messages besides that on the `logcat`.

When I debug it, I see that it's being retried several times. I really don't know why, as other transactions run without issue.

I just want to clone one document from one collection into another collection. Think from "`videos`" to "`favorites`" (I know this can be done outside of a transaction as @Alex points out, but this is just the failing part, the real transaction is longer)

```
private void copy(
    final DocumentReference SOURCEDOCREF, 
    final CollectionReference TARGETCOLREF) {

        Transaction.Function<? extends Void> transaction = new Transaction.Function<Void>() {

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {

                DocumentSnapshot doc = transaction.get(SOURCEDOCREF);
                if (doc.exists()) {
                    DocumentReference favoriteRef = TARGETCOLREF.document("FV_" + doc.getId());
                    Map<String, Object> data = doc.getData();
                    transaction.set(favoriteRef, data);
                    return null;

                    // NOTE: This is reached, ie. the source doc exists
                    // the data recovered, and set into the transaction.
                } else
                    throw new FirebaseFirestoreException("Item does not exist", FirebaseFirestoreException.Code.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        };

        setMode(MODE_SPLASH);
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().runTransaction(transaction)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        (Activity) getContext(),
                        new OnSuccessListener<Object>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Object aVoid) {
                                setMode(MODE_FOLLOW);
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        hide();
                        DialogHelper.customToast(getContext(), e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation about transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> If a transaction reads documents and another client modifies any of
>   those documents, Cloud Firestore retries the transaction. This feature
>   ensures that the transaction runs on up-to-date and consistent data.

So, you can expect that your transaction will be retried if the source document has been modified before the transaction complete.

You can also expect a transaction can fail.

> A transaction can fail for the following reasons:
>
> - The transaction contains read operations after write operations. Read operations must always come before any write operations.
> - The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again.
>     The transaction is retried a finite number of times.
>
> A failed transaction returns an error and does not write anything to
>   the database. You do not need to roll back the transaction; Cloud
>   Firestore does this automatically.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. As you see, I don't do anything like that. That's why I'm thrilled such a simple transaction is consistently failing, while I have ver complex ones that never fail.

Comment: If you think there's a bug here, please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and file a bug report with that information.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: well i'm not sure, just wanted to ask exprienced people if they see a problem in my code

Comment: @DougStevenson Is there any way to abort transaction after specific retries. If I am not wrong max retries for transaction is 25. So I want to know if there is any way to stop the transaction after 5 retries.
In my case OnFailureListener is not called when transaction attempt is failed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use transaction in such a case. To copy a document from a location to another, please use the following method:

```
public void cloneFirestoreDocument(DocumentReference fromPath, final DocumentReference toPath) {
    fromPath.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    toPath.set(document.getData())
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In which `fromPath` is the location of the document that you want to be moved and `toPath` is the loaction in which you want to move the document.

The flow is as follows:

> 1. **`Get`** the document from **`fromPath`** location.
> 2. **`Write`** the document to **`toPath`** location.

Comment: will try ASAP. However, can you think of a reason of why my previous question does not work? It does exactly the same, only inside of a transaction.

Comment: besides , i think there might be need for a transaction (not sure?) as one user might be deleting that document just while it's written, or something like that.

Comment: It's not. You are using this line of code: `setMode(MODE_FOLLOW);` inside `addOnSuccessListener` which has an asynchronous behaviour. Which means that by the time you are running the transaction, that line of code is not yet called.

Comment: Please take a look at the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) to see at what transaction are ment for.

Comment: Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: `setMode(MODE_FOLLOW)` is on the SuccessListener, that as I understand, is called on the UI Thread AFTER the transaction has been executed. Anyway OnSuccessListener is Never been called. It retries the operation 5 times and I want to know why.