# Firestore transactions conditional update?

Tags: android, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to check to see if a value saved in the database matches the user selection, if it does then update it otherwise don't do anything.

I've tried the following, but get an exception:

> Caused by: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Every document read in a transaction must also be written.

Here's my code:

```
//update toolbar titles if they match
final DocumentReference adminDocRef = mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID);
mDbase.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot adminSnapshot = transaction.get(adminDocRef);
        String toolbarTitle = adminSnapshot.getString("displayedUser");
        if (userName.equals(toolbarTitle)) {
            transaction.update(adminDocRef, "displayedUser", userName);
        }
        // Success
        return null;
    }
})
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success!");
    }
})
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
            }
        });
```

Are transactions capable of being conditional?  If not how would you solve this problem?  Seems silly to have to do a separate get then nest an update inside of it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding the condition outside the query?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Eminem.  Could you please be more specific?  The condition is based upon what is currently in the field that I want to update.  The only way I can see doing this is doing a separate query/get() on the field then execute the transaction depending on the result, but that then seems to negate the use of the transaction to begin with...in that case I guess I would do a regular update.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065035/9025311) from [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) ,from [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

A transaction can fail for the following reasons:

- The transaction contains read operations after write operations. Read operations must always come before any write operations. `//not your case`
- The transaction read a document that was modified outside of the transaction. In this case, the transaction automatically runs again. The transaction is retried a finite number of times.

In your case I would try

```
if (userName.equals(toolbarTitle)) {
//transaction operations 
}
```

See if that works!

Comment: Thanks for the response Eminem.  However if you see from my code exxample, in order to get the toolbarTitle value I need to get the info from the snapshot I'm trying to update.  Based upon the answer from Alex, it is as I suspected that currently it seems that Transactions have issues with some types of conditionals if it involves not guaranteeing a write operation.  I posted a feature request for this, and I'm going to also ask the peeps in the firestore forum about it.  Thanks.

Comment: @BrianBegun did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

So in order to update my toolbarTitle conditionally, I would have to cascade my Firestore operations this way:

```
DocumentReference adminDocRef = mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID);
    adminDocRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document.exists()) {
                    //assign document value to toolbarTitle
                    toolbarTitle = document.getString("displayedUser");
                    if (userName.equals(toolbarTitle)) {
                        DocumentReference adminDocRef = mDbase.collection("admins").document(adminID);
                        adminDocRef
                                .update("displayedUser", toolbarTitle)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, "Displayed child has been updated");
                                    }
                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "Error: updating displayed child", e);
                                    }
                                });
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

It's a bit disappointing that I would have to do it this way, as it seems having it wrapped inside of a transaction would make more sense.  I'm hoping that they allow conditional behavior inside the Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, google has a class called [Tasks](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) in which you could use to make firestore calls synchronous.

So following your example, you could fix it into something like:

```
try {
        DocumentSnapshot adminDocument = Tasks.await(adminDocRef.get());
        if (adminDocument.exists()) {
            String toolbarTitle = adminDocument.getString("displayedUser");
            if (userName.equals(toolbarTitle)) {
                Tasks.await(adminDocRef.update("displayedUser", userName));
                //Success
            }
        }
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        //Error
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Error
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This way you don't need listeners and at the same time it is a conditional update. I know this is late but hopefully it'll help someone.

[UPDATE]:
Please note that `Tasks.await(...)` call should not be called on the main thread, a solution would be using `AsyncTask`.